# Access Three.js object in array

Tags: javascript, three.js

For a course I need to develop a simple game using Three.js. I make the following array of spotlights:

```html
function loadLights(roomWidth, roomHeight) {
    let spotlights = [];
    fetch(configLights).then(res => res.text()).then(data => {
        const doc = yaml.load(data);
        const ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(doc.ambientLight.color);
        ambient.intensity = doc.ambientLight.intensity;
        scene.add(ambient);
        let isAmbient = true;
        for (const r in doc) {
            const room = doc[r];
            if (isAmbient) {
                isAmbient = false;
                continue;
            }
            for (const spot in room) {
                for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    const obj = room[spot];
                    let sl = new THREE.SpotLight();
                    sl.intensity = obj.intensity;
                    sl.decay = obj.decay;
                    sl.distance = obj.distance;
                    sl.penumbra = obj.penumbra;
                    sl.castShadow = true;
                    sl.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
                    sl.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
                    sl.receiveShadow = true;
                    scene.add(sl);
                    spotlights.push(sl);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    //START
    console.log(spotlights);
    return spotlights;
}
```

I am using Parcel that's why I need to use fetch to open the yaml-file. The content of the yaml-file is like this:

```
ambientLight:
  color: "0x404040"
  intensity: 0.3
room:
  spotRoom:
    intensity: 1.4
    decay: 10
    penumbra: 0.5
    distance: 100
```

When i print the array "spotlights" in the console i get the following:
[image]

How do i access these objects? When i try `spotlights[0]` it gives back *undefined*.

Comment: It looks like `spotlights` gets initialized properly. Can you show more of your code? I think `spotlights[0]` should work because if what you show in the picture is `spotlights ` then the zeroth element is there. Also don't use pictures, please. Use printed output.

Comment: I updated the post. I inserted the whole function and the yaml-file that holds the config of the spotlights.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I still don't see anything wrong with your code though. Maybe it's a scope problem? If you are trying to access `spotlights` outside the function `loadLights ` that won't work because `spotlights` is defined inside the function. That's why your `console.log` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `fetch()` is an **async** function and you are logging the result immediately before the spotlight is populated. Wait for fetch to complete e.g. using another async function:

```
async function doLog() {
    const spotlights = await loadLights(roomWidth, roomHeight);
    console.log(spotlights);
}
doLog();
```

**Foot note:** `.then` in loadLights function is not wrapping your console.log and is not enough to get the benefit of using a `promise`.